# Updating Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python

I'm reading per line a file and creating new entries for my dictionary:

Suppose that the first line after parsing and splitting will have an entry like this:

```
dict = {"A":{"B":1}, "G":{"P":2}}....
```

then I continue to line 2 and say there is an arbitrary lines to read:

And both keys "A", and "G" appeared again along with them are another entries of values:

Suppose the Second line contained:

```
dict = {"A":{"H":10}, "G":{"L":5}}....
```

Now my question is that, whenever my program reads from a file instead of resetting the information stored for an existing key, like "A", "G". I would like to do have this instead:

```
dict = {"A":{"B":1,"H":10}, "G":{"P":2,"L":5}}
```

then it should keep on updating whenever it says an existing key in the dictionary or make a new entry otherwise

Answer (score 2):

This would be easier to show with an example of the file. But it's easy enough:

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(dict)
for line in file:
    for outerkey, innerkey, value in parseline(line):
        mydict[outerkey][innerkey] = value
```

This would still overwrite the `"H"` value in `{"A":{"B":1, "H":10}}` if it received `'H'` as an `innerkey`, but otherwise, it will behave as you directed. Assuming I understand you...

Comment: As [Artsiom Rudenka](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585152/updating-dictionaries-in-python/6585251#6585251) says, be sure not to use `dict` as a variable name, even if it's only a [metasyntactic variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable) in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use 'dict' as variable name.

You can also use the following code:

```
a = {"A":{"B":1}, "G":{"P":2}}
b = {"A":{"H":10}, "G":{"L":5}}

def append_to_dict(dataDict, dictToAppend):
    for k,v in dictToAppend.iteritems():
        if k in dataDict:
            dataDict[k].update(v)
        else:
            dataDict[k] = v
    return dataDict

print append_to_dict(a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have created the dict by parsing a line, update your *master* dict thus:

```
master = {}

master.setdefault('A', {}).update({'B':1})
# {'A': {'A': 1}}
master.setdefault('A', {}).update({'H':10})
# {'A': {'A': 1, 'H': 10}}
master.setdefault('G', {}).update({'P':2})
# {'A': {'A': 1, 'H': 10}, 'G': {'P': 2}}
master.setdefault('G', {}).update({'L':5})
# {'A': {'A': 1, 'H': 10}, 'G': {'L': 5, 'P': 10}}
```

Alternatively, you could use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
master = defaultdict(dict)
master['A'].update({'B': 1})
```

So, your code will look something like:

```
infile = open('myfile')
master = {}
for line in infile:
    # parse the line
    d = {'A': {'B': 1}}
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        master.setdefault(k, {}).update(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `try/except` on `KeyError` like so:

```
try:
    mydict["A"].update(new_dict_a_info) #try to update existing "A" dictionary
except KeyError:
    mydict["A"] = new_dict_a_info # "A" dictionary wasn't in dict
```

where `new_dict_a_info` is a dictionary containing your new information

**Edit**: As pointed out in other answers, `dict` is not a good choice for a variable name since it hides the builtin `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(dict)
# fd = open(...)
while line in fd:
   key, value = parseline(line)
   result[key].update(value)
```

Also, do not use built-in names for variables (`dict`).